# First angular directive: static table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Running myself in circles, I just can't seem to piece together what I need to do here.

I want to write a directive with the following syntax:

```
<my-table data="(some json)">
    <my-column binding="json.property" header="Name" />
</mytable>
```

Nothing fancy (yet, but I have to get over this hump first). Receive a JSON string, create a table based on the child directives. Can anyone throw together just a barebones example to get me running?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use a directive for this?  You could create a service that receives the JSON string and then returns "table-formatted" data that you could construct the HTML table from.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "create a table based on the child directives"?  That needs more explanation.

Comment: Actually a directive is fine for this.  Especially if the data is duplicated.

Comment: Yes a directive would be overkill for just this but I plan to add more to it. I was just trying to not overload the question. Basically I wanted to create a table with the data property, but using the child elements "my-column" to define the columns and headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a simple table, something like this should be sufficient to get you started:

https://jsfiddle.net/edbrepzu/

Angular:

```
// controller
function Controller($location) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.data = [
    {band: 'Led Zeppelin',id: 1},
    {band: 'The Pixies',id: 2},
    {band: 'Beck',id: 3}
  ];
}

// directive
function myTable() {
   var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<table><tr ng-repeat="d in data"><td>{{d.band}}</td><td>{{d.id}}</td></tr></table>',
      scope: {
         data: '='
      }
   };

   return directive;
}
```

HTML:

```
<my-table data="ctrl.data"></my-table>
```

Personally, I'm a fan of templateUrl rather than template in the directive because the template url is a bit cleaner when the html code gets heavier.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I agree with the templateUrl usage. I'm wanting to be able to define table headers as well though, ideally with the "my-column" elements in my example. Any guidance there?

Comment: Do you know the names of the headers you want to use or would it be dynamic?

Comment: They would be coded into the HTML, not generated at runtime. But they would be different per instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend looking at this site:

http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

It's helped me a lot when I got started on AngularJS, and should provide enough clarification.